# How to install Parsing API in Netbeans?

Tags: scala, netbeans, dependencies, netbeans-7, netbeans-plugins

I am running the latest Netbeans (7.4 beta), and am trying to install the [Scala plugins](https://github.com/dcaoyuan/nbscala).

Unfortunately I am getting this error:

[image: error]

I have tried adding `http://deadlock.netbeans.org/hudson/job/nbms-and-javadoc/lastStableBuild/artifact/nbbuild/nbms/updates.xml.gz` to my plugin repo list, but nothing on the new plugin list it provides is relevant to Parsing API.

How do I rectify this [Parsing API](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-modules-parsing-api/index.html) issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question is answered here: [Can't install nb-scala on NetBeans 7.4rc1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030401/cant-install-nb-scala-on-netbeans-7-4rc1)

A working plugin for 7.4 can be downloaded here (**nbscala-7.4**_2.10.x-1.6.1.1.zip): http://sourceforge.net/projects/erlybird/files/nb-scala/7.x_2.10.x/

Comment: This worked for me, but make SURE that the actual file you download has "7.4" in the name and not "7.x" - SourceForge will try to offer up the wrong file by default as the "latest version."