# Can't install nb-scala on NetBeans 7.4rc1

Tags: scala, netbeans

I've installed NB 7.4rc1, and downloaded nb-scala from
http://sourceforge.net/projects/erlybird/files/nb-scala/
(the 2013-03-11 version)

NetBeans complains that:

```
 Some plugins require plugin Parsing API to be installed.
 The plugin Parsing API is requested in implementation version 6.  The following plugins are  
 affected:  Scala Core       Scala Editor
```

I've installed the extra plug in source recommended in [Netbeans plugin parsing api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696448/netbeans-plugin-parsing-api)

For no avail.

Any ideas? thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Scala plugin uses a implementation version of a NB API. That means it uses a hardcoded version and thus it isn't compatible to any other version of NetBeans.

Please contact to the plugin author to create a compatible package for 7.4

Comment: By now one is available here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/erlybird/files/nb-scala/7.x_2.10.x/

Comment: @Ben Do you know which version of NBs should I download in order to have a smoothly Scala plugin installation?

Comment: @yannis: There is a new package at their download page: http://sourceforge.net/projects/erlybird/files/nb-scala/7.x_2.10.x/nbscala-7.4_2.10.x-1.6.2.0.zip/download . The name implies that is is compatible to NB7.4

Comment: Ok @Ben thnx, I installed NB 7.2 without any issues.